# Flask application traceback doesn't show up in server log

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm running my Flask application with uWSGI and nginx.  There's a 500 error, but the traceback doesn't appear in the browser or the logs.  How do I log the traceback from Flask?

```
uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:9000 --wsgi-file /var/webapps/magicws/service.py --module service:app --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto /var/log/magicws/magicapp.log
```

The uWSGI log only shows the 500 status code, not the traceback.  There's also nothing in the nginx log.

```
[pid: 18343|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {34 vars in 642 bytes} 
[Tue Sep 22 15:50:52 2015] 
GET /getinfo?color=White => generated 291 bytes in 64 msecs (HTTP/1.0 500) 
2 headers in 84 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Run in development mode by setting the `FLASK_ENV` environment variable to `development`. Unhandled errors will show a stack trace in the terminal and the browser instead of a generic 500 error page.

```
export FLASK_ENV=development  # use `set` on Windows
flask run
```

Prior to Flask 1.0, use `FLASK_DEBUG=1` instead.

If you're still using `app.run` (no longer recommended in Flask 0.11), pass `debug=True`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

In production, you don't want to run your app in debug mode. Instead you should log the errors to a file.

Flask uses the standard Python logging library can be configured to log errors. Insert the the following to have send Flask's log messages to a file.

```
import logging
handler = logging.FileHandler('/path/to/app.log')  # errors logged to this file
handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)  # only log errors and above
app.logger.addHandler(handler)  # attach the handler to the app's logger
```

Read more about the Python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html) module. In particular you may want to change where errors are logged, or change the level to record more than just errors.

Flask has documentation for [configuring logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/logging/) and [handling errors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/).

Comment: I don't want to look in a separate file, I just want to look in the main log output. How can I do that? My flask is running inside a docker container so having a separate file for errors is just cumbersome.

Comment: @LennartRolland to log to the standard error, you just need to use `handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `FLASK_DEBUG=1` environment variable when running the app as a service. Only do this temporarily, and note that enabling debug mode on a production server is a security issue.

Upstart (default in Ubuntu 14.04)

```
# /etc/init/uwsgiapp.conf
env FLASK_DEBUG=1
script
  // upstart exec section
end script
```

Systemd (default in Ubuntu 16.04, Arch)

```
[Service]
Environment="FLASK_DEBUG=1"
# other parts
```

Supervisord

```
[program:flask]
environment=FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Typically the logs will be somewhere in `/var/log/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the user and group permission in your code. You can see it using "top" command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Flask-Debug](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Debug/) extension as an alternative. Of course, this should never be enabled on production.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_debug import Debug
app = Flask(__name__)
Debug(app)
app.run(debug=True)
```

Next, go to http://localhost:5000/_debug to preview the logs.

> [flask-appconfig>=0.10](https://github.com/mbr/flask-appconfig) supports automatic initialization of [Flask-Debug](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Debug/) while developing, allowing you to completely omit it from your own code (and therefore production deployments).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `exc_info=True` when you log the error:

```
from flask import current_app, jsonify    

@users.route("/")
def get_users():
    try:
        users = get_users()  
        return jsonify(users), 200
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({"message": str(e)}), 400
```