# Internal Server Error: Dash on Flask on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**NB:** Dash is a python package used to build dashboards by plotly (website [here](https://plot.ly/products/dash/)). Flask is a python package used to build python web frameworks (website [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and AWS tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html/)). I am using python 3.6 and all package versions can be seen below in requirements.txt

**Problem:** I get an error when launching my Dash app onto my AWS EB.

When I run locally on 127.0.0.1:8050 my dash works. However when I `$ eb deploy` I get this on my AWS EB URL:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

My file structure is as so (where `eb-flask` is my flask directory):

```
~/AWS/servers/flask-s
  |-- eb-virt                   }
  |    |-- bin                  }
  |    |-- include              } virtualenv files etc
  |    |-- lib                  }
  |    `-- pip-selfcheck.json   }
  |
  |-- eb-flask              <--- where I ran eb init
  |    |-- application.py
  |    |-- requirements.txt
  |    |-- .gitignore
  |    |-- .elasticbeanstalk
  `         `-- config.yml
```

When using `$ eb config`:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
  NumProcesses: '1'
  NumThreads: '15'
  StaticFiles: /static/=static/
  WSGIPath: application.py
```

My application.py code is pretty much lifted from https://dash.plot.ly/deployment as test.

```
import flask
import os
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

#app = dash.Dash(_name_)
#server = app.server

server = flask.Flask(_name_)
application = dash.Dash(_name_, server=server)

application.css.append_css({"external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"})

application.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2('Hello World'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['LA', 'NYC', 'MTL']],
        value='LA'
    ),
    html.Div(id='display-value')
])

@application.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('display-value', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def display_value(value):
return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    application.run_server(debug=True)
#app.run_server()
```

requirements.txt is obviously pip freeze. At this point it is just the required packages for flask, dash and plotly:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
dash==0.21.1
dash-core-components==0.22.1
dash-html-components==0.10.1
dash-renderer==0.12.1
decorator==4.3.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
gunicorn==19.8.1
idna==2.6
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
nbformat==4.4.0
numpy==1.14.3
pandas==0.23.0
plotly==2.6.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Something is obviously wrong server-side. When I run `(eb-virt) $ python application.py` I can access the site locally. I get this response from a HTTP GET:

```
(eb-virt): eb-flask $ python application.py 
 * Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 190-847-760
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018 18:41:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018 18:41:31] "GET /_dash-layout HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018 18:41:31] "GET /_dash-dependencies HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018 18:41:31] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018 18:41:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Yet when I `$ eb deploy` I get the aforementioned Internal Server Error. I appreciate any help.

When I [enable logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722143/flask-application-traceback-doesnt-show-up-in-server-log), I get `application.logger.addHandler(handler) AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'logger'` locally. On deploying, there are no errors appended to the log file, it just remains blank.

Comment: do you have a `python` folder in `/opt` ?

Comment: @Jack Just wondering if you figured this out, I'm having a similar problem

Comment: I changed tactic: I moved the dash app into __init__.py like so:
```def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    dashapp = dash.Dash(__name__, server=app, url_base_pathname='/dashapp')
    dashapp.layout = <DASH LAYOUT CODE>``` then I created a route:
```@app.route('/dash', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def dash_one():
        return redirect('/dashapp')``` Which worked when I went to the URL /dash

Comment: NB: only works locally. I'm still trying to upload to AWS

Comment: Did it worked for you? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Jack was this ever resolved? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the `application.run_server(debug=True)` method has `localhost` as a default host. This means that the app is deployed to `127.0.0.1` and you can access it only from the inside of the machine where it's running. This explains why you could only access the app locally (whether it was from your computer or inside the instance). When deploying to Elastic Beanstalk you need to specify host as `0.0.0.0` - all IP addresses (deploying with `debug=True` in production is discouraged!):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Check [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-python-flask/blob/master/application.py) GitHub sample Flask app Beanstalk deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion with the name" application"
this worked for me:
application = flask.Flask(**name**)

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,server=application)
```